# Is there any field which is opposite of is_superuser?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Well my problem is quite complicated I think. Actually I am making building a website and i have almost made complete login and sign up functionality and suddenly i noticed a strange behavior with my website. I was login with by admin on a tab and at the same i was logging in to my website and i notice that before logging in there was an option appearing for logout but i did not log in at that sport. When i clicked on the logout button then my superuser just log out. So that when a super user is login from admin site than every new user can see log out button so which can click and superuser will log out. What kind of logic i can apply after that when all the users are login and only logout button appear otherwise not. I am trying with the following code. Please help me if you can.

-----base.html----

```
{% if user.is_active and user.is_authenticated and user.is_not_superuser %}
       <a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" class="get-started-btn">Logout</a>
       {% endif %}
      {% else %}
         <a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" class="get-started-btn">Get Started</a>
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: You're working in the same browser, so all tabs share the same session cookie and have the same session information. Use two different browser instances if you want to test two different users at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much. This brief explanation is really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log in admin panel, you are also logged in website automatically. That's why you see Logout button. The same session and cookies

And use `if not user.is_superuser` if you still need this.